Синонимизировать [графики] и [график]
Предлагаю синонимизировать метки

графики (52 вопроса) нет описания
график (186 вопросов) описание есть

Основная - графики (Метки: множественное или единственное число?). Ещё нужно будет не забыть перенести описание.

Готово!
Объединие:
updating post history, 59 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 52 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 50 rows affected
updating ForYou nudges, 0 rows affected
destroying 'графики': [графики] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records for type Question had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records of type Question had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for target tag, new count: 236
tag remapping of [график] and [графики] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
0 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!

Переименование:
updating post history, 263 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 236 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
Target tag 'графики' doesn't exist, renaming 'график' to 'графики'
rename result: 1 rows affected
tag remapping of [графики] and [график] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
4 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
6 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym график -> графики was approved!

